# No space left in device error despite being empty

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems, fat32

Why am I getting `No space left on device` when I try to create more than `32767` files in my vFat USB Flash Drive?

### Info

- Flash drive is empty (freshly formatted)

```
$ df -H
> Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
> /dev/sdb1        16G  2.1M   16G   1% /media/cmhteixeira/cmhteixeira-usb
```

- gnome disk shows:

```
Partition Type: W95 FAT32 (LBA)
Contents: FAT (32-bit version)
```

I keep reading online that FAT32/vFat have some limitations, including:

- Maximum of 65,534 files in a single directory. Less if the file names are not (8.3).

I am creating these files in a single directory( not necessarily root directory), with the format `12345678.txt`. But after creating the first 32767 such files, I get `no space left on device` error. It is suspicious that the maximum number of files is exactly half the maximum I read on the internet (2^16-2=65,534 vs 2^15-1=32,767).

Do you know why?

(I can create more files if I create them within separate directories)

Comment: In a nutshell, use exFAT instead.

Comment: Thanks. I am more interested in trying to understand the reason, rather than looking for a solution. Can you elaborate on your suggestion?

Comment: FAT32 is very old and, in most aspects, really outdated. In your question you already mentioned some of its limitations.

Comment: @Hearth : I suppose, minus two for `.` and `..` - so 65534 user-made entries (as the useful theoretical max).

Comment: Is there a reason for so many files?   `tar` or zip them instead ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

FAT32 32-bit short file names [must also be uppercase](https://serverfault.com/a/1013729/411612) (technically any ASCII character in the range below 0x80, excluding space), to hit the maximum of 65,534 files.

Long file names will take up more 32-bit entries, so all of your files are taking 2 chunks resulting in half the max files

Comment: This is because FAT long filenames are stored using "hidden" directory entries adjacent to the "real" directory entry, with the Unicode filename stored in the fields that would otherwise be used for the name, attributes, mtime, etc. Each LFN can store up to 13 characters, and the filename length limit is 255 characters, so a single file can occupy up to 21 directory entries (20 LFN entries plus one "real" one). In this case the names are all 11 chars, so every file takes up two entries.

Answer (score 12):

You already have the answer

> I keep reading online that FAT32/vFat have some limitations, including:
>
> Maximum of 65,534 files in a single directory. Less if the file names are not (8.3).

You are creating a filename with extension `txt`.  For 8.3 format, the filenames have to be all capitals.  Try using `.TXT` instead.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the other answers, a second directory entry is created with the long filename, since "txt" is lowercase (instead of uppercase) and thus a LFN entry is generated to store that.

However, since it's only a case difference in the extension, it is possible to avoid the LFN by saving this on 0x0C byte, which can be enabled on Linux with the mount option `shortname`:

> If a filename contains only lowercase letters, or is a combination of a lowercase basename with an uppercase extension, or vice versa; and has no special characters, and fits within the 8.3 limits, a VFAT entry is not created on Windows NT and later versions of Windows such as XP. Instead, two bits in byte 0x0C of the directory entry are used to indicate that the filename should be considered as entirely or partially lowercase. Specifically, bit 4 means lowercase extension and bit 3 lowercase basename, which allows for combinations such as "example.TXT" or "HELLO.txt" but not "Mixed.txt". Few other operating systems support it. This creates a backwards-compatibility problem with older Windows versions (Windows 95 / 98 / 98 SE / ME) that see all-uppercase filenames if this extension has been used, and therefore can change the name of a file when it is transported between operating systems, such as on a USB flash drive. Current 2.6.x versions of Linux will recognize this extension when reading (source: kernel 2.6.18 /fs/fat/dir.c and fs/vfat/namei.c); the mount option shortname determines whether this feature is used when writing.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system#VFAT_long_file_names